# cordova/phonegap InAppBrowser passing data to opened window

Tags: cordova

I want to pass some object data to opened window, which can not be passed with parameters in url.

How can I do that? Thanks.

[update]
Now what I do is, implement some functions `setSomeData(...)` in that html, to set some value. Because I have a complicated object to pass to new window, I should add many that kind of functions.

`var win = window.open('some_page.html', '_blank');
    win.addEventListener('loadstop',
      function() {
        console.log("call in loadstop");
        win.executeScript({code: "setFormData(" + theObject.somevalue + ")"});
        // setFormData(..) is a function in some_page.html
      });`

Comment: Do you have a Window Handle? Or did they implement window.postMessage() ?

Comment: I checked the document, it seem that the InAppBrowser doesn't have the window handle. Because it is used in mobile,it will open a new WebView or open system browser, I don't think it can get the window handle, like in desktop browser.

Comment: InAppBrowser does provide a window handle, but the window is a custom window object with most standard properties overwritten. For example, the `window.addEventListener()` method is still available.

Answer (score 0):

InAppBrowser does not support window.postMessage method. AFAIK, the only one way is to perform a JS-injection via executeScript method, which you have used. What was the question?

Comment: Accept only string value. If I tried to pass variable then its give me blank value.